# Custom method in Rails Model that Combines DB Column Values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model

I am trying to create a custom method called `full_address` that takes the values of the address, city, state, and zip columns together.

Here is what my rails model `location.rb` looks like.

```
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :address, :city, :state, :zip, :latitude, :longitude
  def full_address
    [address, city, state, zip].compact.join(', ')
  end
  geocoded_by :full_address
  after_validation :geocode
end
```

Does that work? If so, how?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it works, adress, city, state and zip are methods generated to access the instance variable value. Here is an example to explain

```
def address
    "address"
end

def city
    "city"
end

def state
    "state"
end

def zip
    "zip"
end

[address, city, state, zip].compact.join(', ') # => "address, city, state, zip"
```